# c++でconst char*型の文字列をテンプレート関数で連結したい

Tags: c++

c++はstring型を使ってやれば文字列を簡単に扱えると思うのですが、あえて`const char*`型を使って文字列を扱おうと思うのですが、どうすれば`const char*`型の文字列を連結できるのですか？

例: "abc" "abcc" の二つの`const char*`型を連結して "abcabcc" と一つの`const char*`型に入れたいです。調べてこの関数を使って入れたのですが、`rsize_t`型と`size_t`型の違いについても教えていただけますでしょうか？

```
template<typename type> type f(type a,type b) {
    cout << "テンプレート関数\n";
    return a + b;
}

template<> const char* f<const char*>(const char* x, const char* y) {
    //cout << "明示的特殊化\n";
    char* xx = const_cast<char*>(x);
    rsize_t t = sizeof(xx);
    strcat_s(xx, strlen(xx), y);  //ここの関数で書き込みアクセスエラーが出ます。
    cout << xx;
    return  "a";
}

int main() {
    cout << f<const char*>("abc", "abcc");
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: user20098さんの回答の中で言及されていますが、明示的に指摘を。文字列を結合するということは新たな文字列を作るということ、であればその文字列のメモリをどう管理するのかの観点が質問文では抜けています。`std::string`であればオブジェクト自身が文字列を管理しており、デストラクタがきちんとメモリ解放を行います。しかし`const char*`は文字列の先頭を指すポインターでしかないため、どこでメモリ確保しどこでメモリ解放するかを検討・決定しなければなりません。これは回答者では決定できない内容です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2つ誤りがあると考えます。

1. 呼び出し元で渡している引数`"abc"`には結合後の文字列`"abcabcc"`"を格納するだけのサイズがない可能性があります。
2. 呼び出し元では文字列定数を渡していますが、多くのコンパイラでは文字列定数を変更不能なメモリ領域に配置することが多いため、結合する際にアクセスエラーになる可能性があります。

動作させるには、次の2つのどちらかの修正を行うとよいと思います。

＃一長一短です。後者はメモリリークの可能性があるので、前者の方が比較的よいと思います。

1. 呼び出し元で`"abc"`を結合後の文字数以上の配列に格納してテンプレート関数を呼び出す

追記
コメントの指摘通り、案1のコード例で配列`z`のサイズ計算が間違ってました。例を訂正します。
(`sizeof(xx)`だと`sizeof(const char*)`なので、期待通りになりません)

```
    int main() {
        const char xx[] = "abc";
        const char yy[] = "abcc";
        // 必要最小限のサイズより大きくなるのは割り切りです。
        char z[sizeof(xx) + sizeof(yy)] = "abc";
        cout << f<const char*>(&z[0], &yy[0]);
        // 以下、略
    }
```

2. テンプレート関数内で動的に結果配列を生成しそれを返す

   ```
   template<> const char* f<const char*>(const char* x, const char* y) {
       char* z = new char[strlen(x) + strlen(y) + 1];
       strcpy(z, x);
       strcat(z, y);
       // zは呼び出し元でdeleteする必要がある。
       return z;
   }
   ```

---

また、`rsize_t`と`size_t`の違いですが、机上で確認した限りだと、

1. `RSIZE_MAX`という現実的な上限値が規定されている。
2. `rsize_t`の値を返す関数は`RSIZE_MAX`を超える結果の場合`0`を返すことができる。

という違いがあるように見えました。
ただし、これはC言語の規格(「C11」の規格)であり、C++言語では規格化されていないように見えましたので、コンパイラ(処理系)によっては対応していないかも知れません。

Comment: で、そこまでいろいろ考えるのであれば素直に `basic_string` を使ってしまうほうがわかりやすいに１票

Comment: 質問者は「あえて`const char*`を使って」(`basic_string`を使えば楽とわかっている)という条件で質問されたので、それに沿った回答をしました。質問者も 774RR さんのように「複雑」と理解してくれればよいと思います。

Comment: 1の方、配列zのサイズの計算間違ってますね。

Comment: alpha さん、ご指摘ありがとうございました。よくある単純ミスをしてしまいました。